# Como acceder al un campo de un multi array con php

Tags: php, json, array, curl

y gracias de antemano...  tengo el siguiente array y necesito llegar a los campos "code":"USD" y "rate":"3,443.6200" estoy tratando de imprimirlo con `$array["time"]["bpi"]["USD"]["code"]` y `$array["time"]["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"]` pero no les llego

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Jan 29, 2019 20:23:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2019-01-29T20:23:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Jan 29, 2019 at 20:23 GMT"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "3,443.6200",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 3443.62
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "2,628.9249",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 2628.9249
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "3,013.2329",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 3013.2329
    }
  }
}
```

Agradeceria su colaboracion gracias

Comment: listo... el error estaba al principio .. debi quitar ["time"] y solo dejar  ["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"]

Answer (score 2):

Eso es, porque el ejemplo que pusiste es un objeto JSON no un arreglo, para acceder puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$data = '{TuJson}';
$r = json_decode($data);
var_dump($r->bpi->USD->code);
var_dump($r->bpi->USD->rate);
```

Comment: si lo que hice fue aplicarle  $data=file_get_contents($url_api_btc);
  $array=json_decode($data, true); y luego accedi como puse anteriormente muchas gracias

Comment: @FranklinLanz, pero no tienes necesidad de convertir el JSON a array, lo puedes leer como JSON, haciendo lo que dice esta respuesta. Además es un código más claro y más elegante: `$objeto->propiedad`  que `$objeto["propiedad"]`